# How can I store Google Location Position in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, google-api-java-client

I'm working with Google Location Api I get the location and listen to the position change. But If I send these location value in SharedPreferences my apps is crash. What is mine mistake?

I want to make a each location change trigger my SharedPreferences value updated.

Mine FragmentActivity class

```
SessionManagement s = new SessionManagement(this);

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("deneme","Your position : " + location.getLatitude()+" " + location.getLongitude());
    s.setLatitude(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
}
```

And mine Session Management Class

```
public class SessionManagement {

static Activity activity;

public SessionManagement(Activity act){
         activity = act;
}

public void setLatitude(String x){
    SharedPreferences sp = activity.getSharedPreferences("sp", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = sp.edit();
    spEditor.putString("latitude", x);
    spEditor.commit();
    m_latitude = x;
}
```

I got these Error

```
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931): java.lang.NullPointerException
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931):    at      com.yuvety.widget.SessionManagement.setLatitude(SessionManagement.java:70)
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931):    at com.yuvety.main.Pager.onLocationChanged(Pager.java:194)
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.gm$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
 05-20 22:45:23.090: E/AndroidRuntime(9931):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you sure `activity` is not null? i bet it is

Comment: Yes, I'm sure because I see value in Logcat.

Comment: well what is at line 70 in `SessionManagement`?

Comment: This line : SharedPreferences sp = activity.getSharedPreferences("sp", 0);

Comment: yeah so activity is null like i said

Comment: Actually you are right.. I'm using SherlockFragmentActivity so I can't send activity. I'm looking why.. Thanks for find an error.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try getActivity() instead of this when you create the new SessionManagement object? As a best practice check for null when you call getActivity() as it may return null if the fragment is not attached yet.
You may also try to use context instead of activity.

Comment: activity inherits context so it does not matter if you use activity or not and he is using this from an activity so `getActivity()` is not available in Activity only a fragment

Comment: You are right, I misread it that he tries to access it from Fragment.
But isn't it a better approach to use context? What if he later tries to access it from IntentService or such?